# Progressbar - progress end border

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-progressbar

I want a progressbar with solid color but a border at the end of progress. 
Say I have a 40% progress bar, I would for it to be like this

[image]

but this is what I get

[image]

Here is what I have tried

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar3"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:max="100"
    android:min="0"
    android:progress="40"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_bg"/>
```

where progress_bg.xml is

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <color android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">

        <clip
            android:clipOrientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="left">
            <layer-list>
                <item>
                    <color android:color="#640000" />
                </item>
                <item android:right="4dp">
                    <shape>
                        <solid android:color="#2586BA" />
                    </shape>
                </item>
            </layer-list>
        </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Note that when progress is 100%, I do get the border

[image]

So looks it is applied for when the bar is 100% but not for partial progress like 40%. How do I get the desired result?

Comment: instead of `<clip>` use `<scale>` and a nine-patch-drawable as a child drawable

Comment: @pskink using scale is filling up the progressbar to 100% even if progress is set to 40

Comment: play with `android:scaleGravity`, `android:scaleHeight` and `android:scaleWidth`

Comment: @pskink if I set scaleWidth to certain percentage, say 50%, it seems to do it but now it is not tied to progress percentage of the progressbar

Comment: it is tied to scaleWidth % and not progress set for the progressbar

Comment: What about `secondaryProgress`? @ProfessorChaos

Comment: Yeah, using secondaryProgress, setting primary to 40 and secondary to 42,  I can get the desired style. I will keep this for plan B and still would like to get this working just with primary progress.

Comment: Oh God, just post it when you find a solution? :D

Comment: [progress=40, no scaleWidth, result=100%] 
[progress=40 scaleWidth=50% result = 50%]

Comment: progress=40 scaleWidth=50% result = 71.9%,  progress=80 scaleWidth=50% result = 90, progress=100, scaleWidth=50% result = 100%

I have no idea what is going on.